# How to soft delete data automatically after 35 days in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table death_notice and notice_time. In notice_time table, there is a column named notice_duration and 35 is stored there which means that the death notice is displayed for 35 days in the website.

Now, I want to soft delete the data that crossed 35 days automatically in laravel 5.6. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Laravel`s Schedule to make a crontab to delete.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling

Answer (score 1):

you can create [laravel scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling) that run every night and execute below query:

```
App\deathnotice::withTrashed()
            ->where('created_at', '>=', deathnotice::now()->subDays($noticetime->notice_duration)->toDateTimeString());
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to check the current time - created_at column, if> 35 days delete ..., Can use Scheduling
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

You can run cron job and check if created_date is greater than 35 days then change the status 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code.It may be help you

```
$noticetime= App\noticetime::find(1);


$deathnotice= App\deathnotice::withTrashed()
                ->where('created_at', '>=', deathnotice::now()->subDays($noticetime->notice_duration)->toDateTimeString());
                ->get();
```

Comment: where should i place this code to run and delete data automatically

Comment: You have to put in your model

Comment: you have create [laravel sceduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling) there you have to put above code